# Почему Java spring repository игнорирует условие выбора из таблицы?

Tags: java, mysql, spring

Мой код репозитория:

```
import org.springframework.data.repository.PagingAndSortingRepository;
import org.springframework.data.repository.query.Param;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Query;
import org.springframework.data.rest.core.annotation.RepositoryRestResource;

import map.model.Exon;
import map.model.ExonTranscript;
import map.model.Transcript;

@RepositoryRestResource(collectionResourceRel = "exon", path = "exon")
    public interface ExonRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<Exon, Long> {
        @Query("SELECT e.seq_region_start, e.seq_region_end, e.is_current   FROM Exon e, ExonTranscript et, Transcript t WHERE e.exon_id=et.exon_id AND et.transcript_id=t.transcript_id AND t.is_current=1 AND t.stable_id='OTTHUMT00000002121'")
        List<Exon> findByexon_id(@Param("exon_id") long exon_id);
    }
```

Если я выбираю разные поля из таблицы - программа реагирует и поля приходят какие требуются, но вот условия выбора после слова `WHERE` полностью игнорируются. Что я делаю не так? Как мне выполнить выборку из нескольких таблиц?

Comment: поставьте запятую после запроса и добавьте параметром nativeQuery = true

Comment: @RomanDanilov на такое он мне выдает ошибку компиляции annotation values must be of the form 'name=value' , нужно добавить импорт или кавычки?

Comment: @Query(value = "select ... ", nativeQuery = true)

Comment: А вы вообще уверены, что условия выборки игнорируются? На чем основаны ваши выводы? Ваш нативный запрос отрабатывает в СУБД правильно?

Comment: @RomanDanilov выполняю этот же запрос в MySqlWorkBench, выбирает 20 элементов соответствующих критерию, выбираю Java - получаю всю таблицу 300 тысяч записей (но толко те поля что запросила) . Пробовала выбрать только с одним id  запись - тоже выбрал всю таблицу. С вашим новым комментарием скомпилировало но результат прежний.

Comment: То есть ставлю в условие e.exon_id=12 и получаю всю таблицу вместо одной записи, А поля в записях указанные после SELECT - корректно приходят те что выбрала.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/79561/discussion-between-roman-danilov-and-mira).

Comment: Похоже  `PagingAndSortingRepository` не поддерживает `NativeQuery`

Comment: @Mira Не шарю, но можно не связывать таблицы ? `FROM Exon e, ExonTranscript et, Transcript t`

Comment: @sank А как их не связывать? Если инфа из трех таблиц выбирается, у двух связь многие ко многим, и промежуточная у них

Comment: @Mira, не я просто привык к JOIN и т.д. отсюда и вопрос)) Без явного написания, он также джоинит все таблицы получается?

Comment: @sank да, может можно и JOIN только проблема в WHERE

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Короткий ответ такой: Потому что `PagingAndSortingRepository` не поддерживает `NativeQuery`, так как мне пагинация и сортировка не нужны, я просто унаследовалась от `Repository`

Comment: Всё он поддерживает, если у вас не совсем древняя версия спринга

Comment: @RomanDanilov вы спрашивали доп инфо - но у меня только начало проекта, кроме представленного репозитория только простые модели всех трех таблиц - итого четыре файла, без контроллера, без вью то есть там и показывать нечего больше. К сожалению вариантов лучше чем костыль в моем ответе пока не нашла, потому пусть повисит.

Comment: Вот модели больше всего интересуют, потому что вы написали, что у вас две сущности связаны через третью таблицу, а запрос у вас на кроссджоинах, что уже неправильно изначально. Просто с таким подходом вы потом столкнетесь с другими проблемами, я написал это в чате

Comment: Да, видимо ошибка в моделях, они у меня никак друг с другом не связаны, простейшие модели трех таблиц. (в чат отписалась)